# Print selected task when the user enters task switching mode in windows

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-os

I want to write a code to do the following:
When the user clicks alt+tab to open the task-switching mode,
then he Moves between the windows using the right or left arrow to choose which one to switch to, I want to print the title of each task he is moving between.
in other words
I want to say something like if the selected tab is google chrome pyautogui.press('enter') to enter this tab else pyautogui.press('right') to go to the next tab in the tab switching window.
here is my code:

```
                # tab =  Code to get the selected tab
                if tab == 'Google Chrome':
                    Do something
```

How can I do that?
[image: This image contains the task switching bar and the screenshots window is selected in my code I want to print ScreenShots in this case]